# Can I have enchant the same item multiple times?

Tags: battle-chasers-nightwar

Some items that I've found appear to have more than one [effect]s listed in their description. I've only tried to enchant each item once, but I'm afraid if I enchant it with something else I'll lose my previous enchantment which was expensive to do.

I have a bunch of questions about this:

- Can I have more than one of my own enchantments on an item?
- Can I enchant an item with the same type of enchantment more than once to stack the effect (at the same or at different color grades)?
- Can I enchant items which already have an [effect] without erasing the existing effects?